# Apache VirtualHost: How to ServerName a port different from 80

Tags: apache, xampp, port, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I use Xampp and I want `test.localhost` to go to `127.0.0.1:81`.

In httpd.conf I wrote:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:81
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:81
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:81>
 ServerName test.localhost
 DocumentRoot "d:\_projects\projectx"
 DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

and to `windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` I added:

```
127.0.0.1       test.localhost
```

But `http://test.localhost` now brings me to `127.0.0.1:80`.

How do I make it go to `127.0.0.1:81`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as your browser is concerned, `http://test.localhost` is `http://test.localhost:80`.

What you want is an Apache redirect...

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
 ServerName test.localhost

 Redirect / http://test.localhost:81
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hm, I see. But I already have something else on port 80 - So I actually don't want to redirect. Still, you're anwser is technically correct, so you deserve the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

Or just go http://test.localhost:81 on your browser instead of using Redirect.