# port 80 blocked by ISP

Tags: http, port

I want to run a web server on my home network but my ISP doesn't let incoming requests from port 80, so I have to use port 81, is there a way I could hide the port number from my domain so that people don't have to type **mysite.com:81** in the address bar?

I tried to use an SRV record but after failing so many times I realized that the browser needs to obey the SRV record and it doesn't so that's why it doesn't work.

**Note**
My ISP also wouldn't let me buy a static IP so I have to use a dynamic dns service provided by noip.com.

Comment: If incoming port 80 is blocked then there is nothing you can do (except hosting your website somewhere else).

Comment: And this is off-topic for StackOverflow... It would be more appropriate at e.g. SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do either port forwarding or redirect requests on server.

For example run server on `8080` port and redirect all requests from port 80 to 8080.

See this: [Apache VirtualHost: How to ServerName a port different from 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823073/apache-virtualhost-how-to-servername-a-port-different-from-80)

Comment: And how would i do that?

Comment: What webserver are you using? You can configure it from your router also (forward requests from 80 port).

Comment: If you are using Apache server simply go to config directory and make changes for port number in `server.xml` file.

Comment: Where is that directory located at again? i can't seem to find it

Comment: It does not help to do port forwarding if port 80 is blocked and you want to use the URLs with default port. I think it is generally a good idea to a) host the application on a hosted server and b) change the ISP if they do not honor net neutrality.

Comment: I agree with @eckes, i.e. no port forwarding will help if the ISP blocks the port, yet this is the accepted answer.   Jordan Jones, why did you accept this answer?  It cannot possibly work.

Answer (score 4):

If your ISP blocks port 80, then you can't run anything, not even a port forwarder, on port 80. Which means your visitors will need to use the port number. Period. Sorry, but there's just no way to make the browser use a different port without telling it to.

One thing that some dyndns providers allow you to do is to create a page that's shown when the domain is offline. You could get jordanjones.noip.com and realjordanjones.noip.com, set jordanjones.noip.com to offline, and make a page there that's nothing but a frameset with one big frame that pulls in realjordanjones.com:81. Don't know if noip.com offers that service, though.

The only real answer is: get a decent provider.