# Dynamic content share on social media

Tags: php, html

I am trying to share dynamic content on Facebook using localhost xampp.My project not uploaded on any domain.Problem is that when I click on facebook link then new dialog box open but the path is using search bar is not working correctly https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=141722133242641&link=http://localhost/JustClick/Professional/show_professional_detail/13..
But when I use the same path http://localhost/JustClick/Professional/show_professional_detail/13 in a separate tab then it's working it's showing my website data.when I use both this URL   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=141722133242641&link=http://localhost/JustClick/Professional/show_professional_detail/13   then it showing " Sorry, something went wrong. " this error.Please help me how I solve this problem.
localhost is my baseurl
Professional is my controller
show_professional_detail is method of controller
13 is the id of professional

```
Here is my code of show_professional_detail method:

    <meta property="og:url"           content="http://localhost/JustClick/Professional/show_professional_detail?id=<?php  echo $row->pro_id; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title"         content="<?php  echo $row->pro_business_name; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:description"   content="<?php  echo $row->pro_email; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:image"         content="http://localhost/JustClick/Professional/show_professional_detail<?php  echo $row->professional_image; ?>" />


            <li><p class="icon show_detail_icon_fb"><a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Facebook" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fb_share('<?php echo base_url('Professional/show_professional_detail/'.$row->pro_id) ?>','<?php echo $row->pro_business_name?>')" class="fbBtm">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/graphics/facebook-icon.png') ?>" width="40" height="40" alt="Facebook" />
            </a></p></li>

Here is my javascript code:

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>`enter code here`


(function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id))
            return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=141722133242641";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


function fb_share(dynamic_link,dynamic_title) {
    var app_id = '141722133242641';
    var pageURL="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=" + app_id + "&link=" + dynamic_link;
    var w = 600;
    var h = 400;
    var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
    var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
    window.open(pageURL, dynamic_title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=yes, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + 800 + ', height=' + 650 + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left)
    return false;
}


</script>

Please help me.
```

Comment: you cant share a localhost address on the web, that's what domain names and IP addresses are for, local host means "this machine"  Think about it, if you can use localhost, and I can use localhost, how does the site know which localhost is mine and which is yours.  You could use your IP address, but it's likely not a static one ( costs more ) so it would be unreliable.  ( meaning you have no guarantee that it wont change )

Comment: i already load my localhost address on facebook developer site.but still its not working.What  is solution of this problem

Comment: use a real IP address....  `127.0.0.1` or `::1` wont work on a remote computer to access your local one.  see Wikkipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost  The very first sentence `In computer networking, localhost is a hostname that means this computer`

Comment: i didnot understand how i use this one.Current i am using this path on facebook link.localhost/JustClick/Professional/show_professional_detail.My id address is 39.40.68.148.so how can i use this ip in this path please help

Comment: further `. It is used to access the network services that are running on the host via its loopback network interface. Using the loopback interface bypasses any local network interface hardware.`  Meaning it doesn't even access any network hardware etc...

Comment: It's not likly that you can use a standard dynamic address for a webserver, most ISPs will block it,  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752990/port-80-blocked-by-isp

Comment: Seriously for the `$5` that it costs per month for a basic hosting account, it's not worth the sweat...   And a domain will run you from `$1` ( godaddy has a sale on them ) to around `$15` per year.

Comment: Oky i am trying this soultion.Then i will tell u its working or not

Comment: Now i used http://127.0.0.1/JustClick/Professional/show_professional_detail/13 this path its working.its open the facebook page without any error.But 1 problem still occur which its not showing the dynamic content of page its showing  127.0.0.1 for posting on facebook

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps:

Step #1: Use the bellow script at the bottom of the page before `</body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      (function (d, s, id){
        var js, fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if(d.getElementById(id))
          return;
        js=d.createElement(s);
        js.id=id;
        js.src="//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.jsBxfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=facebook_app_id";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function fb_share(dynamic_link,dynamic_title){
      var app_id='facebook_app_id';
      var pageURL="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id="+ app_id + 
      "&link" + dynamic_link;
      var w=600;
      var h=400;
      var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
      var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);

    window.open(pageURL, dynamic_title, 
    'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=yes,scrollbars=no,
    resizable=no,copyhistory=no, width=' + 800 + ',height=' + 650 + ',top=' + 
    top + ',left=' + left)
    return false;
    }  
    </script>
```

Step #2: Add this meta tags in under  tag and get content from Database.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="dynamic_page_full_link">
<!-- for inastance http://mywebname.com/View_news/<?php echo $id; ?> -->
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $news_title; ?>">
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $news_message; ?>">
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/files<?php echo $news_image; ?>">
```

Step #3: Your own link for facebook share button.

```
<li>
<p class="icon show_detail_icon_fb">
<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Facebook" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fb_share('<?php echo base_url('Professional/show_professional_detail/'.$row->pro_id) ?>','<?php echo $row->pro_business_name?>')" class="fbBtm">
<img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/graphics/facebook-icon.png') ?>" width="40" height="40" alt="Facebook" />
</a></p></li>
```

That's it.